# Text too small in Firefox when scaling by small factors

Tags: html, css, firefox

When scaling text by extreme factors, firefox is displaying the text smaller than every other browser (tested in IE, Chrome, Safari). I set up a minimal code pen to demonstrate the issue: http://codepen.io/mbuesing/pen/zNBEqG

```
.test {
  transform: scale(0.04); 
  display: block;
  font-size: 3000px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The problem is even more extreme with smaller factors. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it? I need to scale a text for an animation.

Comment: I think this has to do with how Firefox is rendering the text - it seems to have more space surrounding the character at the top and bottom, which means that its deficiency becomes more obvious as you scale it down. It is doing exactly what its supposed to - if you remove the transform you will see that _by default_ the block will be higher than on other browsers, which is probably related to type rendering. This is an inconsistency that will be hard to get rid of. You might want to render text into an image canvas and scale that, as you can know its size... `transform` is not to blame here.

Comment: I don't want to render into an image because of the semantic issues that would imply. I ended up just testing wether the user is on firefox and adapted the scale factor in that case.